# Edge swipe and application exit Android wear 2.0

Tags: wear-os

I am writing the application for Android wear and I need to achieve the behavior similar to Google maps app on Android wear when closing the application.

Usually, the "Swipe-To-Dismiss" gesture (swipe from left to right) closes the application (activity), but could you imagine the situation where you have a picture or map and you need to pan in the application. The pan from left to right always close the app.

There should be a solution described by Google on https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit.html#swipe-to-dismiss.

> *If you want the user to go down the back stack, you can wrap the view in a SwipeDismissFrameLayout object, which supports edge swipe. Edge
>   swipe is enabled when the view or its children returns true from a
>   canScrollHorizontally() call. Edge swipe enables the user to dismiss
>   the view by swiping from the leftmost side of the screen (currently
>   set to 10% of the screen width) and not just anywhere in the view.*

This is implemented in Google maps app for Android wear. Application is closed just in case you start swiping very close to the left edge. It is called "Edge swipe".

The problem is that canScrollHorizontally() must return true and I am not able to set this view property correctly - it is always false. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/SwipeDismissFrameLayout.html

Layout file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.SwipeDismissFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_dismiss_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context="jhettler.wearmaps.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.wearable.view.SwipeDismissFrameLayout>
```

I would like not to implement deprecated classes like DismissOverlayView and use power button to exit the application.

Any ideas or examples how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: The short example of the problem.
https://youtu.be/u7BkprKlReA

How it should work.
https://youtu.be/T8gbQKr95U4

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling swipe-to-dismiss with this code:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

> Disabling swipe-to-dismiss generally is not recommended because the user expects to dismiss any screen with a swipe. In an exceptional case, you can set windowSwipeToDismiss to false and the user would press the power button to exit your app.

This can be found in the [Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/behavior-changes.html) document for Android Wear 2.0. Things like reintroduction of Swipe-to-Dismiss, power button returns to the Watch Face and other changes for Android Wear 2.0 were discussed here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extend SwipeDismissFrameLayout and create a custom class.

I have no problem with this code.

```
public class MySwipeDismissFrameLayout extends SwipeDismissFrameLayout {
    public MySwipeDismissFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySwipeDismissFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySwipeDismissFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, float dx, float x, float y) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.MySwipeDismissFrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yu Kobayashi's answer is effective if `MySwipeDismissFrameLayout` contains a scrollable view.
If no scrollable view exists, you can use [onPreSwipeStart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/SwipeDismissFrameLayout.Callback.html#onPreSwipeStart(float,%20float)).

```
        new SwipeDismissFrameLayout.Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreSwipeStart(float xDown, float yDown) {
                Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point displaySize = new Point();
                display.getSize(displaySize);
                return xDown < displaySize.x / 10;
            }
        };
```

Comment: `onPreSwipeStart` isn't a public method, how are you supposed to override it?

Answer (score 0):

As you note from the Android developer documentation, to activate an edge swipe, your instance of `SwipeDismissFrameLayout`, or at least one of its contained views, has to return `true` when its method `canScrollHorizontally()` is called.

However, in your given layout file, the only contained view is a stock `RelativeLayout`, which returns `false` from `canScrollHorizontally()`.

One way to achieve your aim is to extend `View` and then to override its method `canScrollHorizontally()`, minimally something like this:

```java
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then in your layout file, inside your `SwipeDismissFrameLayout`, put:

```xml
    <com.mydomain.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

assuming your package name is `com.mydomain`.